# xfce shortcut for Terminal

Tags: command-line, xfce, shortcuts

I've just started to use xfce, but I can't set keyboard shortcut for terminal(like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). I go to setting >> keyboard and define the key but it does not work and the error "data hasn't been found" shows up.

Comment: Your version of Ubuntu may be helpful (ctrl+alt+T was already setup in my Ubuntu 18.04).  I looked in mine and the command set for CTRL+ALT+T is `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator`  (note: i copy & pasted into this comment; I expected it to say `xfce4-terminal` but it doesn't)

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.04. I've inserted the command "xfce4-terminal "and i've set CTRL+ALt+T. I think some thing goes wrong. Anyway thanks alot.

Comment: did you try the command as found in mine - ie. `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator`  ?

Comment: Ya, and now it works very well, thank you {guiverc}.